# schematic representation of circular permutation in a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would like to represent digits in a set in a way that the set emphasizes the order of the digits schematically in the set in order to avoid confusion with a set of combinations. For example,

how can I demonstrate $\{1, 2, 3\}$ with order so that the reader knows that here there is circular permutation (and a cycle on $\{1,2,3\}$ with order as important).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [cycle notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation). For example, $(1 2 3)$ is a shorthand for the cycle   $1\mapsto 2\mapsto 3\mapsto 1$.